# Linking/Installing "libpqxx" with Visual Studio 2013 for C++ Connection with PostgrSQL

Tags: c++, database, postgresql, visual-studio, libpqxx

i want to connect postgreSQL with my C++ win32 console application using "libpqxx" with MS Visual Studio 2013 
I tried to search the whole internet but did'nt find any solution or even not any proper tutorial or document on how i can connect that but found nothing.
after 3  weeks of research i'm fed up now but i'm still searching and want to know the proper steps o do this.
I have already installed the following
MS Visual Studio 2013
PostrgeSQL
and downloaded LIBPQXX latest version

OS  Window 10

i want to know the step by step library/api linking and connection guide and i will be very thankful if you are able to provide or attach some images related to steps that help in understanding this all.

and also can i use to build that pqxx library if yes then please tell me how can i do that.

That task related to my university project so please can someone help me i did'nt have much information about libpqxx and how to connect libraries or build them and searched alot about this libpqxx

Thank you in advance

Comment: Where is the problem? Add the PostgreSQL header files  to the include path and the libraries to the link path. Of course, you need 32-bit PostgreSQL to link to 32-bit executables. It is all quite simple.

Comment: hi can you please explain this in step by step format

Comment: I did, didn't I?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60111660/postgresql-connectors-using-vc

Answer (score 1):

You can't with the latest two versions of libpqxx because VS 2013 doesn't support the necessary C++ language specs:

- libpqxx v7 requires at least Visual Studio 2017 for C++17 support. https://github.com/jtv/libpqxx#upgrade-notes

> The 7.x versions require C++17. However, it's probably not a problem if your compiler does not implement C++17 fully. Initially the 7.x series will only require some basic C++17 features such as std::string_view. More advanced use may follow later.

- libpqxx v6 requires at least Visual Studio 2015 for C++11 support. Note that this is so even though the libpqxx has a "VisualStudio2013" folder inside of config/sample-headers/compiler. https://github.com/jtv/libpqxx/releases/tag/6.0.0. (VS 2013 doesn't support, probably among other features, noexcept).

> C++11 is now required. Your compiler must have shared_ptr, noexcept, etc.

Also, inferring from the release notes that C++11 is required as of v6, that presumably means that v5 would be the last version that could be built under VS 2013.